# Can't get Cloned Flask / Heroku app to run

Tags: python, heroku, flask, virtualenv

I've been using laptop A to build a Flask / Heroku app. Have now switched to laptop B and am trying to get the app to run locally. I've setup Heroku and and cloned my app onto B. Whenever I try and run the app `python run.py`...

```
(venv)admins-MacBook-Air:lhv-talenttracker surajkapoor$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/surajkapoor/Desktop/lhv-talenttracker/app/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import views
  File "/Users/surajkapoor/Desktop/lhv-talenttracker/app/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from utils import mandatory_fields_filled, allowed_file, get_activation_link, get_serializer, drop_candidate_on_page, email_to_resumename, role_to_integer, create_bio_field, parse_bio, parse_status, parse_role, get_filename_extension, extract_company_domain, file_upload, candidate_formgrab, analytics_parse_point_in_process, commit_to_analytics, attach_resume_send_email, add_candidate_to_requested, admin_required
  File "/Users/surajkapoor/Desktop/lhv-talenttracker/app/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mail
```

So I run `pip install Flask-Mail` and...

```
(venv)admins-MacBook-Air:lhv-talenttracker surajkapoor$ pip install Flask-Mail
Downloading/unpacking Flask-Mail
  Downloading Flask-Mail-0.9.1.tar.gz (45kB): 45kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip_build_surajkapoor/Flask-Mail/setup.py) egg_info for package Flask-Mail

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask-Mail)
Downloading/unpacking blinker (from Flask-Mail)
  Downloading blinker-1.3.tar.gz (91kB): 91kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip_build_surajkapoor/blinker/setup.py) egg_info for package blinker

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask->Flask-Mail)
Installing collected packages: Flask-Mail, blinker
  Running setup.py install for Flask-Mail
    error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py: Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip_build_surajkapoor/Flask-Mail/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip-jJZpzO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

copying flask_mail.py -> build/lib

running install_lib

copying build/lib/flask_mail.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py: Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip_build_surajkapoor/Flask-Mail/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip-jJZpzO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fy/q_qrg7h16_710hs0qs05pp6m0000gq/T/pip_build_surajkapoor/Flask-Mail
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/surajkapoor/Library/Logs/pip.log
(venv)admins-MacBook-Air:lhv-talenttracker surajkapoor$
```

I see Flask-Mail in my virtual env so I'm confused as to how to get this to run. I tried installing my requirements.txt too but that didn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 0):

Check where that `pip` is coming from, by running `which pip` with your virtualenv activated. It should be inside the virtualenv (you could check the `python` as well just for good measure).

Instead your pip is trying to install things into your global python install, and it's getting permission denied (as normal, without root - which is fine, this is why we use a virtualenv).

Make sure you have an up-to-date virtualenv (>=1.10) and pip (>=1.5). If you didn't, reinstall them and recreate any virtualenvs you made with older ones. Or maybe your virtualenv included global site packages when you made it? This is also not normally what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I missed this. I ran which pip and it reads /usr/local/bin/pip. How would I change it to direct to within the Virtual Env?

Comment: Normally running the `activate` script for the correct virtualenv *should* set the paths correctly for you, however if it doesn't, there is a `pip` script also inside that virtualenv's `bin` folder, which you can run directly. Or if your `python` is correctly the virtualenv's python, you can substitute with `python -m pip`.